Estimating the parameters of an ellipse (part 3)
This post is a follow up of this and this previous ones. I've found an explanation for the following formulas
\begin{equation}
\hat{\ell}_1 \triangleq 2\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{11}} \qquad
\hat{\ell}_2 \triangleq 2\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{22}} \qquad
\hat{\theta} \triangleq \tan^{-1}(\hat{R}_{21}/\hat{R}_{11})
\tag{$\star\star$}
\end{equation}
but I still have some trouble with the second formula
\begin{equation}
\hat{\ell}_1 \triangleq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{11}} \qquad
\hat{\ell}_2 \triangleq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{22}} \qquad
\hat{\theta} \triangleq \tan^{-1}(\hat{R}_{21}/\hat{R}_{11})
\tag{$\star\star\star$}
\end{equation}
Proof of $(\star\star)$
We know that the sample covariance $S$ estimates the true covariance $\textrm{Cov}[y]$ of the distribution behind the generation of the dataset. Thus we have
\begin{equation*}
S \approx \textrm{Cov}[y]
\end{equation*}
Now, consider the case where $y\sim \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta))$ (observations all over the elliptic area). Since $y$ is zero-mean and uniformly distributed all around the ellipse $y'X y \leq 1$, the true covariance in this case is given by
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{Cov}[y]= \frac{1}{\pi\,\ell_1\,\ell_2}\int_{y' X y \leq 1} y\,y' \text{ d}y
\end{equation*}
where the normalizing factor $\pi\,\ell_1\,\ell_2$, which is the area of the ellipse, comes from the PDF of $y$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
p(y)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi\,\ell_1\,\ell_2} & \text{if } y'Xy\leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
For simplicity, consider the case where the ellipse is aligned to the reference axis, i.e. $\theta=0$ and so
\begin{equation*}
X= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1/\ell_1^2 & 0 \\
0          & 1/\ell_2^2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
In order to compute the covariance integral, consider the following change of variables for $y=[y_1\,\,y_2]'$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &\triangleq \ell_1\,\rho\,\cos \phi \\
y_2 &\triangleq \ell_2\,\rho\,\sin\phi \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Then, the integral gets the following form
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{Cov}[y] = \frac{1}{\pi\,\ell_1\,\ell_2} \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
(\ell_1\,\rho\,\cos\phi)^2 & \ell_1\,\ell_2\,\rho^2\,\cos\phi\,\sin \phi\\
\hline
* & (\ell_2\,\rho\,\sin\phi)^2
\end{array}\right]\,\rho\,\textrm{d}\phi\,\textrm{d}\rho = \frac{X^{-1}}{4}
\end{equation*}
from this fact follows
\begin{equation*}
S \approx \frac{X^{-1}}{4}
\end{equation*}
which justifies the definition of the estimate
\begin{equation*}
\hat{X} \triangleq 4\,S^{-1}
\end{equation*}
and, in the end, explains the scaling factor $2$ in the definitions of $\hat{\ell}_1$, $\hat{\ell}_2$ of $(\star\star)$. The general case with $\theta \neq 0$ should give the same result after using much more trigonometry.
An attempt to prove $(\star\star\star)$
Using a similar method, we have to compute the covariance of $y\sim\mathcal{U}(\partial \mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta))$ (observations on the elliptic countour). For simplicity, assume $\theta=0$. In this case we have
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Cov}[y] &\approx \frac{1}{2 \pi \ell_1}\int_{y'Xx=1} yy' \text{d}y
=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,\ell_1} \int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
(\ell_1\,\cos\phi)^2 & \ell_1\,\ell_2\,\cos\phi\,\sin \phi\\
\hline
* & (\ell_2\sin\phi)^2
\end{array}\right]\,\textrm{d}\phi = \frac{X^{-1}}{2\,\ell_1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where I've made use of the parametrization
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= \ell_1\,\cos\phi \\
y_2 &= \ell_2\,\sin\phi
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and the normalizer $2\pi\ell_1$ is a first order approximation of the ellipse perimeter.
Question
The objective is to show that, at least approximately, holds
\begin{equation*}
S\approx \frac{X^{-1}}{2}
\end{equation*}
because it would justify my empirical formulas $(\star\star\star)$. Unfortunately my current result is
\begin{equation*}
S\approx \frac{X^{-1}}{2\ell_1}
\end{equation*}
which works pretty badly even if I consider higher order approximations for the perimeter (which is given by this elliptic integral). I'm wondering if I made some mistake in the "pathological" change of variables from $y_1,y_2$ to $\phi$, where we loose a degree of freedom. I'm suspecting that I'm forgetting some kind of scale factor between $\text{d}y_1\text{d}y_2$ and $\text{d}\phi$.
My question is the following:

How do you compute the following "fake double integral"?
\begin{equation*}
I(X)\triangleq \int_{y'Xx=1} yy' \text{d}y
\end{equation*}


As I was suspecting, I forgot the Jacobian determinant of the transformation between $y_1, y_2$ and $\phi$. Such factor is
\begin{equation*}
\left\lVert \left[\begin{array}{c}
-\ell_1 \sin \phi \\
\ell_2 \cos \phi
\end{array}\right]\right\rVert= \sqrt{\ell_1^2 \sin^2 \phi+\ell_2^2\cos^2 \phi}
\end{equation*}
and so the correct integral is
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{Cov}[y] = \frac{1}{2\pi \ell_1} \int_0^{2\pi} 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
(\ell_1\,\cos\phi)^2 & \ell_1\,\ell_2 \,\cos\phi\,\sin\phi \\
\hline
* & (\ell_2\,\sin\phi)^2
\end{array}\right]\,\sqrt{\ell_1^2 \sin^2 \phi+\ell_2^2\cos^2 \phi}\,\text{ d}\phi 
\end{equation*}
Considering the first order approximation $\ell_2\approx \ell_1$ (so that the ellipse is approximated with a circle with radius $\ell_1$) gives
\begin{equation*}\sqrt{\ell_1^2 \sin^2 \phi+\ell_2^2\cos^2 \phi} \approx \ell_1 \end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{Cov}[y] \approx \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
(\ell_1\,\cos\phi)^2 & \ell_1^2 \,\cos\phi\,\sin\phi \\
\hline
* & (\ell_1\,\sin\phi)^2
\end{array}\right]\text{ d}\phi = \frac{\ell_1^2}{2}\,I_2 \approx \frac{X^{-1}}{2}
\end{equation*}
